# MySQL UPSERT on specific column

Tags: mysql, upsert

I want to insert multiple values to a mysql table but if a specific column is duplicated then update the current row, I already know the insert into on duplicate key statement, but I want to make the duplicate check on a normal column not on a key is this possible in mysql ?

I tried the INSERT INTO on duplicate key but I cant make it work on a specific column

Comment: Please bear in mind that, if the column is meant to be unique but the DB doesn't enforce it, you also need to consider the possibility that you already have duplicates. If so, do you want to update all the matching rows?

Comment: Example please.

Comment: Imagine that the primary key is auto increment if use this query it will upsert depending on this key, but i want to upsert based on duplicate column a for example        INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;

Comment: Then create a unique key on column a

Comment: Thing is this column is not meant to be unique for all kind of records, i will use the upsert only on specific records so it would be meaningless for me to make it a unique key acrros the entire table, is there any workarounds without creating a unique key?

Comment: *is there any workarounds without creating a unique key?* Stored procedure.

Comment: Lack of unique key will sooner or later cause problems if you have multiple concurrent users, this is why mysql insist on having a unique key. Consider using multi-column unique key if you want uniqeness to be enforced for certain rows only as mysql allows multiple null values in a unique key.